# How to save DirectAccess password on Windows 8?

Tags: networking, windows-8, remote-desktop, vpn, passwords

I'm using DirectAccess with a smartcard to connect to the company Intranet. Eventually connection drops for no apparent reason, and when I click on network notification icon, the DirectAccess connection says "Action required". When I click on it, it says "Your credentials are needed". This is annoying because my smartcard *is* connected.

Is there a way to save the password or make the connection last for more time?

Comment: Find out why the connection drops - it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. I only have to login to the desktop using same credentials that I use for DirectAccess (i.e. use a smartcard instead of domain\user). This way, I don't even need to explicitly connect via DirectAccess - it connects automatically and connection never drops. Phew!